# Следует ли выделять запятыми "будто нехотя"?

Tags: пунктуация

Он(?) будто нехотя(?) поднял глаза.

Answer (score 1):

Довольно часто обособляются обстоятельства, выраженные наречиями, чтобы выделить смысл фразы или дать попутное пояснение. ***Меня, как бы нечаянно, обливали водой (Ч.)***В вашем предложении, на мой взгляд, как раз похожая конструкция: сказуемое "поднял глаза", а "будто нехотя" - обстоятельство, выраженное наречием с союзом-частицей "будто". Выделение интонационное тоже напрашивается. Если Вы хотите выделить обстоятельство по смыслу и интонационно, выделяйте его и запятыми на письме.
Но выражение "будто нехотя" по значению близко наречию неохотно, медленно. Поэтому его можно не выделять. Сравнительным оборотом это выражение не является.

Answer (score 1):

"Он, будто нехотя, поднял глаза". Обособление обстоятельства определяется структурой предложения.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

Будто нехотя - устойчивое наречное выражение со значением уподобления, состоящее из сравнительного союза БУДТО и наречия НЕХОТЯ.

Часто применяется в художественной литературе, исполняя различные функции: (1) обособленное обстоятельство, (2)необособленное обстоятельство, (3) однородное обстоятельство, (4) обособленный ряд.

Выбор знака препинания зависит от структуры предложения и часто является авторским, например:

(1) А второй, будто нехотя, отвечал: ― Что, что, разве ты его не знаешь?

(1) Сергей Алексеевич долго, будто нехотя, возвращался к повседневной жизни.

(2) Отец будто нехотя подошел к куче хлама в углу и изо всей силы пнул ее сапогом.

(2) Проходя мимо рабочих, бабушка своим орлиным оком тотчас заметила, что один из них и усердствовал меньше прочих и шапку снял как будто нехотя.

(3) Все засмеялись, но как-то тоже лениво, как будто нехотя.

(3) Вон она...по-прежнему отворяет и затворяет шкафы, шьет, гладит кружева, но тихо, без энергии, говорит будто нехотя, тихим голосом...

(4) ― Мне принесли, ― ответила она, будто нехотя и не взглядывая на него.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что запятые тут ставить не нужно, потому что сравнительный оборот тесно связан по смыслу со сказуемым. Розенталь приводит такой пример: *Он **смотрит** на жизнь **будто сквозь розовые очки***.